# What's an efficient way to select every 6th and 7th element using css nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm using the css nth-child selector to try to add a 20px margin to every 6th AND 7th element in an unordered list.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
          X X        X  X           X  X           X  X
```

So far I've accomplished this by using two separate css selectors:

```
li:nth-child(5n+6){}
li:nth-child(5n+7){}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this pattern using only one nth-child formula?

Comment: Just a pedant note: this is every 4th and 5th element starting from the 3rd, not every 6th and 7th.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The basic function `y = ax+b` maps integer values of `x` to evenly-spaced values `y`. Your target elements are not evenly spaced.

Therefore, you must use `li:nth-child(5n+6),li:nth-child(5n+7)`, there is no simplification possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
li:nth-child(5n+6),
li:nth-child(5n+7) {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Doesn't that work for it?

Comment: "What's an efficient way to select every 6th and 7th element using css nth-child" was the question.

Comment: No, the question was "Is there a way to accomplish this pattern using only one nth-child formula?"